# case statement in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case-when

I have this stored procedure, its working

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myrange()
BEGIN
SET @start = 0;
PREPARE stmt FROM ' SELECT firstname FROM peoples ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,1 INTO @name';
    WHILE @start < 5 DO
        EXECUTE stmt USING @start;
        CASE 
            WHEN @name = 'Ana'
                THEN INSERT INTO mytable (log) VALUES('yes');
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO mytable (log) VALUES('no');
        END CASE;
        SET @start = @start + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

but, if I delete from this procedure, this piece of code:

```
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO mytable (log) VALUES('no');
```

mysqli_error() returns this error: **"Case not found for CASE statement"**.

Someone know, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL CASE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html)

> If no when_value or search_condition matches the value tested and the
>   CASE statement contains no ELSE clause, a Case not found for CASE
>   statement error results.

You must have all options covered.

The MySQL manual is a *great* documentation. Be sure to visit it!

Comment: There are *so may* different things between vendors. You must always be sharp to recognize them.

Comment: ... and even version differences from one product. It seems that using MySQL 5.5.25 *does* allow it.

Comment: The 5.5 documentation repeats the same condition. Is this something you've just tested on a 5.5 server?

Comment: I noticed that to but I tested this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1120). I assume the statement gets executed agains a MySQL database. So either the database where the statement gets executed on SQLFiddle is not a MySQL one or the documentation is not up-to-date.

Comment: Then perhaps you've actually used a value that is *found* by the case statement. Have just tried on **5.5.24** and it fails on `ERROR 1339 (20000): Case not found for CASE statement`. I did not test on **5.5.25** but I will be very much surprised to find that it works.

Comment: You can follow the link to SQLFiddle to verify for yourself but I don't see anything wrong with it. According to the documentation, the statement should fail but on SQLFiddle, it returns two NULL values. The statement is equivalent to this `select case when t = 1 then 'x' end from (select 2 as t) as q`. Can you try this statement on a 5.5.24?

Comment: I now see your error. You have used the [case expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) instead of [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-statement.html)... The two are not the same. The original question relates to the latter.

Comment: Perhaps so but what about [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1125). This is a case expression and a searched case statement. Both of them work.

Comment: No, both these cases make for a case expression, not a case statement. A case statement is a construct in stored routine programming. A case expression, (both versions you used), is a query clause.

Comment: <slap forehead>Thank you Noach, the penny **finally** dropped.</slap forehead>

Comment: Be kind to your forehead. It should serve you for years to come. Name's Shlomi. My pleasure

Comment: Thanks very much Shlomi Noach and  Lieven.