# SELECT CASE param_name END CASE INTO @var in stored procedure using parameters to assign columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to create with parameters.

```
DELIMITER // 
    CREATE PROCEDURE insert_avg(IN area INT, IN checkid INT, IN legend INT)
this_proc: BEGIN

SELECT
    CASE legend
        WHEN 1 THEN "Input_Day"
        WHEN 2 THEN "Input_Week"
        WHEN 3 THEN "Input_Month"
        ELSE LEAVE this_proc
    END CASE;
INTO @LEGEND;

INSERT INTO 
    `input_teamboards` 
    (
        `Input_KPI`, 
        `Input_Month`, 
        `Input_Week`,   
        `Input_Day`, 
        `Input_Value`, 
        `Input_Comparison`, 
        `Input_Area`, 
        `Input_Created`
     ) 
VALUES 
    (
        7,
        IFNULL(SELECT `Input_Month` FROM `input` WHERE `check_id` = checkid, NULL, MONTH(NOW())),
        IFNULL(SELECT `Input_Week` FROM `input` WHERE `check_id` = checkid, NULL, WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())),
        IFNULL(SELECT `Input_Day` FROM `input` WHERE `check_id` = checkid, NULL, DAYOFYEAR(NOW())),
        (SELECT 
            AVG(`Input_value`) 
        FROM 
            `input` 
        WHERE 
            `Area_ID` = area AND @LEGEND = 1),
        2,
        area,
        NOW()
    )

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see the `@LEGEND` variable is being used as part of a subquery for a column name further down.

The problem I'm having is with the case statement, it keeps throwing errors within the case statement:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEAVE this_proc
>        END CASE;
>    INTO @LEGEND;
>    INSERT INTO 
>        `input_teamboards`' at line 8"

I've used these links so far, but stuck on what I'm doing wrong?

 [Mysql Storing a variable with the result of an SELECT CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871014/mysql-storing-a-variable-with-the-result-of-an-select-case)

[Mysql - How to quit/exit from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260157/mysql-how-to-quit-exit-from-stored-procedure)

[case statement in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483167/case-statement-in-stored-procedure)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is LEAVE a column?

Comment: No it is not a column, the columns I'm referring to are `Input_Day`, `Input_Week` and `Input_Month`

Comment: You're trying to combine the usages of a `CASE` *statement* and a `CASE` *expression*. You can't arbitrarily mix and match between the two.

Comment: You can't use `@LEGEND` like this as a column name.  If you want to do that, you'll have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You may want to see this for dynamic statements, [self-promotion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205938/dynamic-statement-executor).

Comment: Thank you all! I'll have a look into dynamic SQL but will be using @TimBiegeleisen ' answer for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite your proc as this.  See below the code for further explanation.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_avg(IN area INT, IN checkid INT, IN legend INT)
this_proc:BEGIN

IF legend NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
     LEAVE this_proc;
END IF;

INSERT INTO input_teamboards
(
    Input_KPI, 
    Input_Month, 
    Input_Week,   
    Input_Day, 
    Input_Value, 
    Input_Comparision, 
    Input_Area, 
    Input_Created
 ) 
SELECT
    7,
    COALESCE(Input_Month, MONTH(NOW())),
    COALESCE(Input_Week, WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())),
    COALESCE(Input_Day, DAYOFYEAR(NOW())),
    (SELECT AVG(Input_value) FROM input WHERE Area_ID = area AND
     ((legend = 1 AND Input_Day = 1)  OR
      (legend = 2 AND Input_Week = 1)  OR
      (legend = 3 AND Input_Month = 1))),
    2,
    area,
    NOW()
FROM input
WHERE check_id = checkid;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The major change I made here was to rewrite your insert query.  I rephrased it as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  This should work because most of your subqueries were referring to the same `input` table.  For the average subquery, I handled the logic involving the `legend` parameter by just checking its value, and then checking the appropriate corresponding column.  This then lets us delete the `CASE` expression you orignally had at the start of your proc.

Comment: The condition `IF legend < 1 OR legend > 3` should be `legend not in (1,2,3)` in case the `legend` is NULL.

Comment: That's much more straight forward, thank you @TimBiegeleisen !